# how to import .ics file and return agenda via javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, icalendar

can someone give me an js lib or an code sample how to import an ics-link and return every event in chronological order?

I just find javascripts for creating an event..

-Tim4497

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [ical.js](https://github.com/mozilla-comm/ical.js/) ? Documentation is [here](https://github.com/mozilla-comm/ical.js/wiki)